# CiviMail forward to a friend not working (Mailing is not forwarded to the given email address.)

Tags: civimail, error

Any ideas on why this is occuring? I click the forward to a friend link in the civimailing in my inbox, fill in an email, then press forward. I am then presented with the error "Mailing is not forwarded to the given email address".

CiviCRM Version: 4.6.14
CMS: Drupal 7.43

EDIT: just tested on another CiviCRM website we manage (same civi version), and the same issue occurred.. I was able to replicate this issue on Drupal6, Drupal7, AND WordPress. Possible CiviCRM 4.6.14 bug?

[image]
[image]